# Does this integral have a proper closed form solution?

Tags: integration

The integral is given by:

$\int_0^L\delta(x-v)H(x-d)dx$

$\delta$ is the dirac delta function and $H(x-d)$ is the heaviside function (equal to 0 for $x\leq d$ and equal to 1 for $x>d$).

Both $v$ and $d$ belong to the intercal $0\leq x\leq L$

Does this integral have a closed form solution?

Comment: What is the interval of integration $L$?

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta Fixed it.

Comment: This is NOT an integral.  It is a functional that is undefined for $v=d$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments are trying to make this more complicated than needed so I have no option but to remove the answer or continue pointless discussions about things that are peculiar and really not what this question was about.

I hope commentators are now thrilled.

I cannot delete the answer so I let someone else make it as complicated as he wants.

Comment: Your first equality is true *if the function* $\;f\;$ is continuous (or, in fact,if it is continuous in compact sets)

Comment: Yes, for Heaviside function it is fine. In general it is not, certainly within the realm of Lebesgue measure/integral theory.

Comment: The distribution is undefined for $v=d$, regardless of how one defined $H(0)$.

Comment: @AleksandarPerisic First, there are no integrals involved here; they are linear functionals that borrow the integral notation.  In fact, your analysis uses formal manipulation and is invalid.  Note that $H(x)$ is NOT even a suitable test function due to its lack of smoothness at $x=0$.  So, it is not meaningful to write $\langle \delta_0,H_0\rangle$.  In fact, we need to apply the notion of distributions of compact support to the theory of generalized functions to assign meaning to $\langle \delta_a, H_b\rangle$ for $a\ne b$ by noting $\delta$ is a distribution with compact support $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

In general

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(x) f(x) dx = f(0)$$

or

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(x-v) f(x) dx = f(v)$$

So in general you would have $H(v-d)$ being $1$ if $v>d$. Elsewhere it is $0$.

A small problem is what to do if $v=d$, for example $v=d=0$ since nothing is nicely defined, there has to be some additional step that justifies the accepted value $0$ if we can justify it.

Probably, it would be advisable then to treat the integral as an improper integral and use this form of Riemann–Stieltjes integral that is shifting $f(x)\delta(x)dx$ towards $f(x)dH(x)$ (We understand here $H(x)$ as a cumulative distribution.)

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^{L}H(x)dH(x)$$

We do it this way since we need to make $H(x)$ a continuous function.

This gives the result $0$ as $H(x)$ is simply a constant either for $L$ or any $\epsilon$. The same goes for any $v=d$.